# Is global pooling necessary in image classification models?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, computer-vision

In many image classification models, the global pooling operation is performed before the classification layer (i.e. fully connected layer) to reduce model complexity. Is the global pooling layer a necessary component in the image classification framework?